# What would happen if my happy home showcase is house full and I get another via streetpass?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I'm just curious about what would happen if my happy home showcase slot was full when I got another via streetpass? Will it disappear randomly or when the person is out of range? Is there any further information available about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The oldest house (that has not been marked as a Favourite) will be removed and replaced with the new house. You can only favourite up to 16 houses.

Source: http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Happy_Home_Showcase

Comment: If anyone can clarify whether "oldest" refers to time a house first appeared, time a house was last updated, or time the house's owner was last Streetpassed, I'll update the answer to clarify. I believe it's the latter, but cannot confirm.

Comment: Oh i See, so we should favorite which is your favorite one..